# How do I combine multiple pdf files to an a4 papersize output?

Tags: pdf, ghostscript

currently I am using

`gs -sPAPERSIZE=a4 -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -q -sDEVICE=pdfwrite sOutputFile=combined.pdf input1.pdf input2.pdf input3.pdf`

for combining my pdf files, however I have noticed, that combined.pdf according to evince's document properties has a paper size of "231 x 314 mm". Is there a way to fix this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try use programs like:

- pdftk ([home page](http://www.pdflabs.com/tools/pdftk-the-pdf-toolkit/))
- PDF Mod ([home page](http://live.gnome.org/PdfMod))
- PDF Shuffler ([home page](http://pdfshuffler.sourceforge.net/))

You can find this in the Software Center

Comment: thanks. This answers my question. Though it does not really solve my problem, since I want to merge multiple documents before printing them, to save paper. I just realized that some of them are .ps files. I think I will stick with gs for a while.